# Multiple values with only one scanner method?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment where I need to do certain calculations in separate methods using data entered by the user. My problem is with the user input. It is supposed to be done with a separate method (I do not think I am allowed to use arrays for storing the inputs). The user should be able to enter as many values they want and then exit with "q". The program should then take the first two numbers, calculate e.g. an area and volume with those (with other methods I did not include here), present the result, take the next two numbers the user entered, calculate and present results. This should be repeated until it reaches the "q" value. So for example:

```
    Enter your values: 9 5 3 7 q
    radius: 9 height: 5
    Area = 254
    Volume = 424

    radius: 3 height: 7
    Area = 28
    Volume = 65
```

A problem I am having is that only the first value is assigned to a variable and then the user has to enter data again for the next variable, even though there's still more numbers left from the first time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack {
   private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int radie, height;

      radie = userInput("");
      height = userInput("");

   }

   public static int userInput(String message) {
      int number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      while (number == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
         System.out.print(message);
         if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            number = input.nextInt();

         }
         input.nextLine();
      }
      return number;
   }
}
```

I understand there are massive flaws in my code here, I'm very lost and not sure where to even start with solving the problem. Any help or tips are very welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you read 'Scanner.hasNextInt()' method documentation? 
There is written: 
Returns:
true if and only if this scanner's next token is a valid int value

So question if

```
 number == Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

doesn't make sens.

Try to ask if hasNextInt() 
returns true or false

Edit: Also 
Why do you assume that after number is always 'q'?

Change condition in while statement

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand your mean, but i did some changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stack {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userInput();
    }

    public static void userInput() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter your values:");
            String message = input.nextLine();
            //Split data with space
            String[] data = message.split(" ");
            int pointer = 2;
            for (String i : data) {
                if (i.equals("q")) {
                    System.out.println("Stopped.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (pointer % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("radius: " + i);
                }
                if (pointer % 2 == 1) {
                    System.out.println("height: " + i);
                }
                pointer++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Affect:

```
Enter your values:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
radius: 1
height: 2
radius: 3
height: 4
radius: 5
height: 6
radius: 7
height: 8
Enter your values:
1 q
radius: 1
Stopped.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for being a little confusing. The calculations (area, volume) I mentioned are done in other methods I did not include. And I don't think I'm allowed to use arrays for the assignment. What it says is "It should be possible to enter multiple values before you press enter. If "q" has been entered the program should quit. If any other letter was entered it shall be ignored" It also says to use nextInt() to read the next int while remaining numbers awaits being read. Not sure if this helps or just confuses more.